# Code is getting into an infinite search when executed via TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The below code is getting into an infinite search when running via TestNG, otherwise giving correct results when executed directly in Main method via Java Application.

```
Boolean iselementpresent = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foreign exchange1")).size()!= 0;
```

Infinite search-->

```
public boolean checkLinkPresence(String linkName){
    Boolean iselementpresent = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foreign exchange1")).size()!= 0;
    if (iselementpresent == true)
        return true;
    else{
        System.out.print("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you best post the whole testclass including the testmethods with testng annotations, maybe there is a mistake, also parent classes that are called

Comment: just to add, for positive scenario i.e. when linkText is present on the webPage output comes correct as expected. But for negative scenario i.e. when linkText is not present on the webPage, code goes into an infinite search.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `main` method in TestNG as everything works with annotations. However make sure your implicit wait time is short so that the command `findElements` timeouts after that. If you have not given an implicit wait, try giving one and then try running your method. Here's an example -

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //set this before you get the url using driver.get()
```

Once your implicit wait time is set, try running your method.

```
public boolean checkLinkPresence(String linkName){
    List elements = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Foreign exchange1"));
    if (elements.size() != 0)
        return true;
    else{
        System.out.print("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write this function...

```
public boolean checkLinkPresence(String linkName)
{
    if (driver.findElements(By.linkText(linkName)).isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.print("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        APP_LOGS.debug("Element " + linkName + " not Present");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your locator had a hard coded string in it `By.linkText("Foreign exchange1")`, so no matter what string you passed the function, it was always looking for that one string.